# How do I increase the value of 'sessionStorage.fgattempt', every time 'fgMade()' or 'threeMade()' is triggered?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am creating a stat tracker for a basketball game I play and I need that every time that I make a field goal or three pointer, that the field goal attempts go up as well. Also may need a way to shorten the javascript code I have written here.

Basically what is being asked is how to go about increasing the value of 'sessionStorage.fgattempt', for every time that both the functions 'fgMade()' and 'threeMade()' are run. It would also be nice to see that 'threeMade()' increases 'sessionStorage.threeattempt' as well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function fgMade() {
      if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (sessionStorage.fgmade) {
          sessionStorage.fgmade = Number(sessionStorage.fgmade) + 1;
        } else {
          sessionStorage.fgmade = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = sessionStorage.fgmade;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
      }
    }

    function fgAttempt() {
      if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (sessionStorage.fgattempt) {
          sessionStorage.fgattempt = Number(sessionStorage.fgattempt) + 1;
        } else {
          sessionStorage.fgattempt = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = sessionStorage.fgattempt;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
      }
    }

    function threeMade() {
      if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (sessionStorage.threemade) {
          sessionStorage.threemade = Number(sessionStorage.threemade) + 1;
        } else {
          sessionStorage.threemade = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = sessionStorage.threemade;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
      }
    }

    function threeAttempt() {
      if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (sessionStorage.threeattempt) {
          sessionStorage.threeattempt = Number(sessionStorage.threeattempt) + 1;
        } else {
          sessionStorage.threeattempt = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = sessionStorage.threeattempt;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
      }
    }

    function block() {
      if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (sessionStorage.block) {
          sessionStorage.block = Number(sessionStorage.block) + 1;
        } else {
          sessionStorage.block = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result5").innerHTML = sessionStorage.block;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result5").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
      }
    }

    function steal() {
      if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (sessionStorage.steal) {
          sessionStorage.steal = Number(sessionStorage.steal) + 1;
        } else {
          sessionStorage.steal = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result6").innerHTML = sessionStorage.steal;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result6").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
      }
    }

    function defRebound() {
      if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (sessionStorage.defrebound) {
          sessionStorage.defrebound = Number(sessionStorage.defrebound) + 1;
        } else {
          sessionStorage.defrebound = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result7").innerHTML = sessionStorage.defrebound;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result7").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
      }
    }

    function offRebound() {
      if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (sessionStorage.offrebound) {
          sessionStorage.offrebound = Number(sessionStorage.offrebound) + 1;
        } else {
          sessionStorage.offrebound = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result8").innerHTML = sessionStorage.offrebound;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result8").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
      }
    }

    function turnover() {
      if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (sessionStorage.tocount) {
          sessionStorage.tocount = Number(sessionStorage.tocount) + 1;
        } else {
          sessionStorage.tocount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result9").innerHTML = sessionStorage.tocount;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result9").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
      }
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>FGM</th>
        <th>FGA</th>
        <th>3PM</th>
        <th>3PA</th>
        <th>BLK</th>
        <th>STL</th>
        <th>DREB</th>
        <th>OREB</th>
        <th>TO</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="result1">N/A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="result2">N/A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="result3">N/A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="result4">N/A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="result5">N/A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="result6">N/A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="result7">N/A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="result8">N/A</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="result9">N/A</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p><button onclick="fgMade()" type="button">FGM</button></p>
  <p><button onclick="fgAttempt()" type="button">FGA</button></p>
  <p><button onclick="threeMade()" type="button">3PM</button></p>
  <p><button onclick="threeAttempt()" type="button">3PA</button></p>
  <p><button onclick="block()" type="button">BLK</button></p>
  <p><button onclick="steal()" type="button">STL</button></p>
  <p><button onclick="defRebound()" type="button">DREB</button></p>
  <p><button onclick="offRebound()" type="button">OREB</button></p>
  <p><button onclick="turnover()" type="button">TO</button></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Dunde seriously use monogame or unity2D.  You'll have to learn c# but it's less of a headache

Comment: It's not for a game that I'm making but rather a game that I play that doesn't keep stats that I would like kept track of. I'm just a natural stat head I guess. XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that this is the kind of thing you're looking for? FYI. This solution will still operate without having access to session storage, which in my opinion is nearly an essential part to include.

```js
// A simple way to encapsulate the code into some object, 
// yet due to being a self invoked function, it still has the 
// luxury of 'private' properties. 
const App = function(myNameSpace) {
  let state = { // Initial app state.
    fgmade: 0,
    fgattempt: 0,
    threemade: 0,
    threeattempt: 0,
    block: 0,
    steal: 0,
    defrebound: 0,
    offRebound: 0,
    turnover: 0
  };


  // A simple method to load the state from session storage.
  const loadState = () => {
    try {
      if (sessionStorage.getItem("appState") != null) {
        state = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("appState"));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // todo?
    }
  };


  // A simple state method to update the applciation state in session storage.
  const setState = () => {
    try {
      sessionStorage.setItem("appState", JSON.stringify(state));
    } catch (e) {
      // todo? 
    }
  };


  // A simple function to reste the state.
  const resetState = () => {
    Object.keys(state).forEach(k => state[k] = 0);
    setState();
    render();
  };


  // A VERY simple render method. 
  const render = () => {
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = state.fgmade;
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = state.fgattempt;
    document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = state.threemade;
    document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = state.threeattempt;
    document.getElementById("result5").innerHTML = state.block;
    document.getElementById("result6").innerHTML = state.steal;
    document.getElementById("result7").innerHTML = state.defrebound;
    document.getElementById("result8").innerHTML = state.offRebound;
    document.getElementById("result9").innerHTML = state.turnover;
  };


  // This is the 'bulk' of the code, where it works out which property to update.
  const buttonClickHandler = (e) => {
    const txt = e.target.textContent.replace(/\ /g, '').toUpperCase();

    switch (txt) {
      case 'FGM':
        updateProperty('fgmade');
        updateProperty('fgattempt');
        break;
      case 'FGA':
        updateProperty('fgattempt');
        break;
      case '3PM':
        updateProperty('threemade');
        updateProperty('fgattempt');
        updateProperty('threeattempt');
        break;
      case '3PA':
        updateProperty('threeattempt');
        break;
      case 'BLK':
        updateProperty('block');
        break;
      case 'STL':
        updateProperty('steal');
        break;
      case 'DREB':
        updateProperty('defrebound');
        break;
      case 'OREB':
        updateProperty('offRebound');
        break;
      case 'TO':
        updateProperty('turnover');
        break;
      default:
        resetState();
    }
  };


  // A simple function to update some data.
  const updateProperty = (key) => {
    state[key] += 1;
    setState();
    render();
  };


  // A function responsible for binding events to updates & whatnot. 
  const dispatchEvents = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((button, index) => {
      button.setAttribute('data-index', index);
      button.addEventListener('click', buttonClickHandler);
    });
  };


  // Public method to state the app. 
  myNameSpace.launch = () => {
    loadState();
    render();
    dispatchEvents();
  };


  // Make sure to return the public object.
  return myNameSpace;
}({});


// Very lazy solution to document.ready.
setTimeout(App.launch, 250);
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button#reset {
  background: red;
  border-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>FGM</th>
      <th>FGA</th>
      <th>3PM</th>
      <th>3PA</th>
      <th>BLK</th>
      <th>STL</th>
      <th>DREB</th>
      <th>OREB</th>
      <th>TO</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="result1">N/A</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="result2">N/A</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="result3">N/A</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="result4">N/A</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="result5">N/A</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="result6">N/A</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="result7">N/A</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="result8">N/A</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="result9">N/A</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



<p><button>FGM</button></p>
<p><button>FGA</button></p>
<p><button>3PM</button></p>
<p><button>3PA</button></p>
<p><button>BLK</button></p>
<p><button>STL</button></p>
<p><button>DREB</button></p>
<p><button>OREB</button></p>
<p><button>TO</button></p>
<p><button id="reset">RESET</button></p>
```

Comment: This answer is very good, clear and concise jQuery (which I was going to end up having to use anyways) and easiest to read of the answers, especially with the comments in line. :) This one also didn't increment the 3PA when 3PM was triggered, but like I said easy fix so don't worry about it:)

Comment: @drent2001 I'm glad you think so! :) Happy I could've helped! :)

Comment: One more thing if you don't mind.. How would I go about adding a reset button so i dont have to close the page every time i want to erase the values?

Comment: @drent2001 I've updated the source code, I think it now includes the relevant reset functionality?

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My two cents..

```js
    var
      basketball_scores_head = document.querySelector('#basketball-scores thead tr'),
      basketball_scores_body = document.querySelector('#basketball-scores tbody tr'),
      All_ScoreButton        = document.querySelectorAll('#basketball-scores  button'),
      Scores_Vals            = {},
      asStorage              = (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined");
    ;

    All_ScoreButton.forEach(bt_elm=>{
      let
        e_TH = document.createElement('th'),
        e_TD = document.createElement('td'),
        ref  = bt_elm.dataset.count.split(' ')[0]
        ;
      e_TH.textContent = ref;
      e_TD.textContent = "N/A";
      e_TD.id          = "count_"+ref;

      basketball_scores_head.appendChild(e_TH);
      basketball_scores_body.appendChild(e_TD);

      Scores_Vals[ref] = 0;

      bt_elm.onclick = IncreaseScore;
    });

    if (asStorage) {
      if ( sessionStorage.getItem('basketball_scores') )
      {
        Scores_Vals = JSON.parse( sessionStorage.getItem('basketball_scores'));
        for (let cnt in Scores_Vals ) {
          document.getElementById("count_"+cnt).textContent = Scores_Vals[cnt].toString();
        };
      } else {
        sessionStorage.setItem('basketball_scores',  JSON.stringify(Scores_Vals) );
      }
    }

    function IncreaseScore(e) {
      e.target.dataset.count.split(' ').forEach (cnt =>{
        Scores_Vals[cnt]++;
        document.getElementById("count_"+cnt).textContent = Scores_Vals[cnt].toString();
      });
      if (asStorage) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('basketball_scores',  JSON.stringify(Scores_Vals) );
      }
    }
```

```css
      table#basketball-scores,
      table#basketball-scores th,
      table#basketball-scores td {
        border : 1px solid grey;
      }
      table#basketball-scores th,
      table#basketball-scores td {
        width  : 100px;
      }
      table#basketball-scores button {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<table id="basketball-scores">
  <thead>
    <tr></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td><button data-count="FGM FGA">+</button></td>
      <td><button data-count="FGA">+</button></td>
      <td><button data-count="3PM FGA">+</button></td>
      <td><button data-count="3PA">+</button></td>
      <td><button data-count="BLK">+</button></td>  
      <td><button data-count="STL">+</button></td>
      <td><button data-count="DREB">+</button></td>
      <td><button data-count="OREB">+</button></td>
      <td><button data-count="TO">+</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: they way you write JS looks like C# : )))

Comment: I like the idea of having the buttons included inside of the table but the 3PM doesn't increase the 3PA (which is an easy fix for me to make now that I see how it is done) but otherwise nice ;).

Comment: To increase 3PA by 3PM click, just change :  **<button data-count="3PM FGA">** to :  **<button data-count="3PM FGA 3PA">**

Comment: They are both right but the other answer helped me learn a bit more which is why I chose it as the MOST helpful.